# How to bulk upsert in kdb+

Tags: bulk, upsert, kdb

It is possible to bulk upsert into a partitioned table. I have tried several of syntax combination and none works.

Ex.

```
`:2015.12/calls/ upsert (1; 4389; 2015.12.01T07:56:50) // single upsert works
`:2015.12/calls/ upsert (1 2; 4389 4397; 2015.12.01T07:56:50 2015.12.01T07:56:58) // do not work
`:2015.12/calls/ upsert ((1; 4389; 2015.12.01T07:56:50);(2; 4397; 2015.12.01T07:56:58)) // do not work.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `upsert` a *table* i.e.:

```
/ substitute `COL1`COL2`COL3 with actual column names
`:2015.12/calls/ upsert flip `COL1`COL2`COL3!(1 2; 4389 4397; 2015.12.01T07:56:50 2015.12.01T07:56:58)
```

Comment: You know how to do it using the java or c# interface? I need to build a giant string or there is a better alternative?

Comment: @nohros use the `c.Flip` object to create a table in java/c#. This will get serialized properly via the api. So you can do something like (assuming k is the c object) `k.k("upsert", ":2015.12/calls/",flip)`